# batch building source code in a makefile

Tags: c, makefile, wildcard, gnu-make

I have a large number of small C programs (all single .c files) and I'd like to build them all into separate executables. That is, `prog-01.c`, `prog-02.c`, etc. should be built separately and the result should be an individual executable for that program.

I'm relatively new to using wildcards in makefiles and I'd appreciate some help. Here's what I've done so far:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Werror

SRCS:=$(wildcard *.c)
OBJS:=$(SRC:.c=.bin)

all-gcc: $(SRCS)
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRCS) -o $(OBJS)

run-%-gcc: prog-%-gcc
       @./$(<)

prog-%-gcc: prog-%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean: 
    @rm *.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was going down this path, I'd probably use:

```
CC     = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Werror

SRCS  := $(wildcard *.c)
PROGS := $(SRCS:.c=)
OBJS  := $(SRCS:.c=.o)

all: $(PROGS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(PROGS)
```

This converts each file `program.c` into an executable `program`, using the default rule to build a program from a C source file.

Comment: Wow, that worked great! could you elaborate a bit more on what's going on here?

Comment: You know how the wildcard works, generating a list of file names ending `.c`.  The next assignment creates a list of names with the `.c` suffix replaced by an empty string, effectively removing the `.c`.  These are deemed to be the programs to make.  Of course, `make` knows how to create a program from a single C source file.  The `all` target will be up to date when all the programs are up to date.  So the standard built-in rules take care of all the hard work.  The OBJS macro contains the object file names, assuming you're on Unix.  The `clean` target removes the programs and object files.

Comment: Ah, that's what I wasn't getting; I didn't realize that make can automatically build stuff without an explicit rule. In that case, how would I modify this to use an explicit rule? I need to make another rule which will run all of them simultaneously? using `./$(PROGS)` only runs the first program and then treats the others as arguments.

Comment: It can do a lot automatically.  `make -f /dev/null prog-01 prog-02` would build `prog-01` from `prog-01.c` and would build `prog-02` from `prog-02.cpp` (or many other language suffixes).

Comment: ah, very cool, I'm gonna have to take that into consideration for my exam. Now with regards to running all these programs with make (yes,I know it's weird) how would I do that? I've tried making another variable `EXEC := $(PROGS: prog = ./prog)` which I though would add a `./` to the front of the name. Instead it did nothing.